# EAR project conversion to maven - web module stop working

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb, war, ear

I am new in EAR applications development. I am trying to build application with the following structure:

- EAR as wrapper for below
- WEB module
- EJB module

(I am using Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio as IDE and wildfly as server)

After creation of above structure i tested it - everything worked fined.

I wanted to add maven support to whole solution so according to found articles I used wizard: right click on project "Configure" -> "Convert to maven project". I did it for ejb and web module firstly and then for ear. I also modified ear pom.xml file and application.xml file.

After this conversion my web module stop working. Attempt to view welcome page returns error 404.

Below you can find EAR pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sri3</groupId>
  <artifactId>sri3</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>
          <earSourceDirectory>EarContent</earSourceDirectory>
          <version>7</version>
          <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
          <webModule>
            <groupId>sri3.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>sri3.web</artifactId>
          </webModule>
          <ejbModule>
            <groupId>sri3.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>sri3.ejb</artifactId>
          </ejbModule>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sri3.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>sri3.web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sri3.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>sri3.ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Below you can find EAR application.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="7">
  <display-name>sri3</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>sri3.web.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>sri3.web</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>sri3.ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

I found several articles and questions with wide description of proper EAR configuration but none of them helped me. What I ommmited?

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Should build a project for maven as follow :

Main Project

--------Child Project(EJB)

--------Child Project (WEB)

--------CHild Project (EAR)

If you have a netbeans , netbeans build a simple project if you select maven enterprise template
Good luck

Comment: Ok. So if I good understood I should wrap all projects including ear one in parent project? What kind of project should it be?

Comment: It is a pom project

Comment: This project just contain sub project , if you look at the sample project of netbeans you completely understand the structure